# unionall function returns duplicate data

Tags: orientdb

i am using unionall function to get the combined results of multiple queries but i get duplicate data , 
sample example  :

```
select expand($res) let $a = (select from #3:1) , $b = (select from #3:1) , $res = unionall($a,$b)
```

i get duplicate data ,

even tried by querying rid , but still same result

```
select $res let $a = (select rid from #3:1) , $b = (select rid from #3:1) ,$res = unionall($a,$b)
```

how do i get unique values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct(@this)
from (select expand($u) as res
      from (select $u 
            let $a = (select from #3:1),
                $b = (select from #3:1),
                $u = unionall($a,$b)) )
```

Note that "select rid from #3:1" is quite different from "select @rid from #3:1", which in turn is different from "select from #3:1".

Comment: Thank you peak , but How to get entire document  from above query than jus rid ?

Comment: Use `expand(_)`, that is, replace "distinct(@this)" by "expand(distinct(@this))".

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select expand($res) let $a = (select from #3:1) , $b = (select from #3:1) , $res = intersect($a,$b)
```

I replaced unionall with intersect.

Comment: Not surprisingly, `intersect` gives the set-theoretic intersection, not a union. For example: `> select expand(distinct($u)) let $a = (select from #11:0), $b = (select from [#11:0,#11:1]), u=intersect($a,$b)` gives
`#11:0`
but
`select expand(distinct($u)) let $a = (select from #11:0), $b = (select from [#11:0,#11:1]), u=unionall($a,$b)`
gives `#11:0 #11:0`